# Application error on Heroku on deploying rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm facing the Heroku deploy error. When I deploy my rails 5 app on Heroku the following error occurs:

> "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for
>   details".

My Heroku app logs is this

```
2018-01-11T11:31:08.702143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-01-11T11:31:08.687436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-01-11T11:31:56.372775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=concept-car-dealer.herokuapp.com request_id=61c90fd0-3588-4f34-b463-45cc6c37e73e fwd="103.255.6.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-01-11T11:31:57.235468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=concept-car-dealer.herokuapp.com request_id=0edb9bee-a765-4500-98b2-09b0826082c9 fwd="103.255.6.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-01-11T11:31:56.859412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=concept-car-dealer.herokuapp.com request_id=b72c7768-541c-42db-b7f1-6f02a853fef2 fwd="103.255.6.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-01-11T11:31:55.750150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=concept-car-dealer.herokuapp.com request_id=780a212f-5fa1-4143-9b26-d245acb50444 fwd="103.255.6.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

[Here is the link of my Heroku App](https://concept-car-dealer.herokuapp.com/) .  [And here is the link of my GitHub repo](https://github.com/devdap/Concept-Car-Dealer)

Comment: Can we please have the logs above the crash, to try and understand what was going before crash?

Comment: Run `heroku logs --tail`  and view the page, It might give you a more readable error, if it does post there here too.

Comment: Have you seen the doc? I think there is complete rails app deployment solution to Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5